# D3 mouse events touch events i.e. click -> supported touch event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been looking for examples for using D3 on a mobile device with touch events instead of mouse events, but am struggling to find anything that maps what touch event replaces which mouse event for example, a `click` or `dblclick`. Thus, I have struggled to get started on "converting" my D3 visualizations to support touch.

I need appropriate touch events for:

- Zooming (or will it work for both?): 
  `var zoomed = d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([scaleExtentMin, scaleExtentMax]).on("zoom", partitionZoom);`
- `click`
- `dblclick`

So the main conversion I would need is `click` --> supported touch event.

How can I do this with D3? Or is there an alternative library that would work well with D3 that can handle the touch events?

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: a click event should still be triggered. but you may want to look at [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/).

Answer (score 1):

what ever event is supported by html containers is supported by svg. click and tap events are the same except for the 300ms delay. you can use hammer like previously suggested or just jquery mobile

Comment: `SVG` does do bubbling. [Here's](http://bl.ocks.org/vicapow/6955981) a block, and [here's](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#SVGEvents) the W3 spec.

Comment: lol, lots have happened in 3 yrs. check the timestamp of the answer.

Comment: I realize, but the W3 spec is from 2011. Just letting anyone who arrives here from Google know

Comment: i don't have clear recollection on why i said it but i am almost certain that had to do with browser compatibility at the time. i am almost certain i had issues bubbling events for the application i was developing  at the time. either regarding bubbling from within the svg tree or from svg to DOM i can not recall the specific issues. How ever if you think is best i can just remove this answer and avoid confusion

Comment: Ah I see. Well, considering that the question doesn't ask about bubbling and that the rest of your answer is pertinent, perhaps it's best to just omit the bubbling part.